# In need of GSM codec specifications in specific format

Tags: red5, codec, gsm, sdp

- What is the default encoded frame size of gsm codec?
- What is the default decoded frame size?
- What are the media attreibutes?
- What is the codec id?

For example same questions for G729's answers are 20, 160, "fmtp:18 annexb=no" and 18 respectively. I am working on a softphone  and I want to add the gsm codec to it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you're looking for, from [RFC 3551 (RTP Profile for Audio and Video Conferences with Minimal Control)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551) in section [6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551#section-6):

```
           PT   encoding    media type  clock rate   channels
                    name                    (Hz)
               ___________________________________________________
               <snip>
               3    GSM         A            8,000       1
               4    G723        A            8,000       1
               <snip>

               Table 4: Payload types (PT) for audio encodings
```

so your SDP body will look, with the boring bits cut away, like this:

```
  m=audio 49170 RTP/AVP 4
  a=rtpmap:4 GSM/8000
```

for a GSM-only connection.

Answer (score -1):

Actually SDP should better look like this:
    v=0
    o=alice 2890844526 2890844526 IN IP4 host.atlanta.example.com
    s=
    c=IN IP4 host.atlanta.example.com
    t=0 0
    m=audio 49170 RTP/AVP 3
    a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000/1
And encoded length is `33 in bytes` and decoded lenght is `320 bytes which equals to 160 PCM frames`.